# how to Arrange datatables in Dataset designer

Tags: visual-studio

I have a datasets with 18 datatables; they are all jumbled up which makes it hard to find any specific table is there a way to order them.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much searching i found too possible solutions

### Solution 1

Just delete the XSS file and reopen the dataset designer

### Solution 2

- Select All tables
- Ctrl + X
- Ctrl + V

Hope it helps anyone

Comment: Sometimes it's the simplest of things that makes the biggest of differences...